# Problemas al retornar File en Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Estoy realizando una api la cual esta siendo construida en asp.net web api, pero me estoy encontrando con un problema y es que al momento de retornar un metodo File me dice que no es invocable, pero he visto en muchos ejemplos donde lo utilizan sin problema:
Este es mi codigo asp.net:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(string nombreArchivo)
{
    string directorio = "C:\\Users\\usuario\\Desktop\\imagenes\\";
    string ruta = directorio + nombreArchivo
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(ruta))
        return File(ruta, "application/octet-stream")
    else return BadRequest("No existe la imagen");
}
```

Comment: Agrega el codigo de como lo estas invocando, conoces la herramienta Fiddler te ayuda a ver cual es la url del llamado y cual es la respuesta, o dependiendo del navegador tambien puedes analisar esta info.

Comment: @MiguelZarate el error ocurre en c#, no al momento de invocar la api

Comment: Para analizar un problema debes visualizar todos los elementos, la url, el metodo asi como los argumentos llamados y si hay un problema de conversion de los mismos del lado del servidor.  Te invito a que des un recorrido en https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour